# How to Show text retrieved from database on JButton, JTextArea in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am trying to build a quiz app and I managed to build the database. I created a GUI using the card layout to switch between panels and I tried to retrieve the questions and options from from the database to a JtextArea with no success. My question is how do I get the visual components (jtext area,jbutton to display the content from the database) I want them to automatically set the text according with the question number.

this is my code

```
   package quizzGUI;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.List;

import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.management.Query;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class quizzMain {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel Menu;
    private JPanel Playing;
    private JPanel Score;
    private final ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    public JTextPane textPane;
    public JButton btnA;
    public JRadioButton rdbtnB;
    public JRadioButton rdbtnC;
    public JRadioButton rdbtnD;
    public JTextArea textArea;


    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    quizzMain window = new quizzMain();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */

    Connection connection = null;
    public quizzMain() {
        initialize();
        connection = sqlConnection.dbConnector();

    }

    private void initialize() {

        Connection connection = sqlConnection.dbConnector();
        Statement stmt=null;

        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

        final JPanel Menu = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(Menu, "name_668313932787145");
        Menu.setLayout(null);
        Menu.setVisible(true);

        final JPanel Playing = new JPanel();
        Playing.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Playing, "name_668321772390383");
        Playing.setLayout(null);
        Playing.setVisible(false);

        final JPanel Score = new JPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(Score, "name_668324579994343");
        Score.setLayout(null);
        Score.setVisible(false);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("C QUIZZ");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 14));
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(123, 47, 169, 40);
        Menu.add(lblNewLabel);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Integer i=0;

                Playing.setVisible(true);
                Menu.setVisible(false);
                    try{
                        String query = ("SELECT * FROM Question  ");
                        PreparedStatement pst=connection.prepareStatement(query);
                        ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
                        do { 

                                btnA.setText(rs.getString("ANSWERA"));



                        }while(rs.next());

                    }catch(Exception e ){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    }           

            }
        });
        btnStart.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
        btnStart.setBounds(167, 176, 89, 23);
        Menu.add(btnStart);

        JButton btnFinish = new JButton("Finish");
        btnFinish.setBounds(335, 227, 89, 23);
        Playing.add(btnFinish);
        btnFinish.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Score.setVisible(true);
                Playing.setVisible(false);
            }
        });





        JButton btnNextQuestion = new JButton("Next");
        btnNextQuestion.setBounds(10, 227, 89, 23);
        Playing.add(btnNextQuestion);

        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(20, 11, 387, 41);
        Playing.add(textArea);

        JButton btnA = new JButton("New button");
        btnA.setBounds(20, 84, 381, 41);
        Playing.add(btnA);





        JTextArea txtrScore = new JTextArea();
        txtrScore.setBounds(87, 74, 244, 43);
        txtrScore.setText("Score:");
        Score.add(txtrScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: `textArea.setText("something")`?

Comment: You select first the text from DB into a string. Then, depending on the component, you use the appropriate method (Jbutton - `setLabel`, JTextArea - `setText`, etc)

Comment: `"i tried to retrieve the questions and options from from the database to a JtextArea with no sucess..."` -- without telling us the details and showing us pertinent code, there's no way of our knowing what you may be doing wrong, and our best advice will be for you to check the tutorials. If you still need more specific help, please consider improving this question, including telling the details and creating and showing your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't mention your code, its difficult to give you a short precise example. I would recommend you to go through this [tutorial](https://coderanch.com/t/486519/databases/retrieving-database-data-textarea) which retrieves information (name and number) and display it in [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).

Extracting the key points from the tutorial below:

**Database connection establishment and fetching information**

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String db =  "databasename";
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String user = "xxxx";
String pass = "xxxx";
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstatement = null;

Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db , user, pass);

pstatement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name, phonenumber FROM tablename");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
ResultSet rs = pstatement.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()){
    String name = rs.getString(1);
    int phonenumber = rs.getInt(2);
}
```

**Set text in JTextArea**

Then use `setText` method of `JTextArea` to set the text. For example, `recordTextArea.setText(name + " " + phonenumber);`.

Comment: @carlos no problem, go through the tutorial, it is pretty easy and will give you a comprehensive idea.